# What value to give for "scope" option when I want to access an Azure function API that is protected with Azure AD in Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-functions

I am working on an Azure Function API that is protected by Azure AD, it's working fine when I request it with browser once I logged in with a valid account, but when I tried with postman it still shows unauthorized access,

I have got an access token to send with the request, but for the scope property I have given is this value, `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` which I think might be the problem. But not sure what I am doing wrong and what to put in the `scope` field in the `get new access token`option in postman to authenticate to my API.

HTTP Request Postman Making

```
GET /api/events/active HTTP/1.1
Host: moya-backend-ascentic.azurewebsites.net
Authorization: Bearer ****IHqMgweN86fDnyL4jvz9P6ZllpjjD9t***
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 655e0672-4928-409e-a709-841a92ee6f14,22cbf978-f196-4099-ae10-d162d3068507
Host: moya-backend-ascentic.azurewebsites.net
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

Comment: Please share your request sample.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are asking about the HTTP Request right, I just updated the post

Comment: Yeah `HTTP` request. You were right

Comment: How did you get the token? Paste your request here will be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope should be: `your-api-client-id/.default`.
Replace your-api-client-id with the client id/application id for your API app in Azure AD.

Now since browser-based login seems to be working, you may have setup the wrong kind of authentication on the API.
If the token still doesn't work, you'll need to setup JWT authentication on the app instead of browser/cookie based.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **v2.0 endpoint**, the scope should be {your_client_id}/.default. Just like @juunas said.

[image]

If you are using **v1.0 endpoint**, you only need resource parameter. The resource should be {your_client_id}

[image]

**Note:** If you are using the 'get new access token' function in postman, the **Access Token URL** should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`